# How to limit Google Drive App Permissions at login

Tags: ios, google-drive-api

I am using the standard iOS Google Drive SDK login mechanism with scope kGTLAuthScopeDrive (or "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive").  During login, after providing the user name and password, the view window shows:

```
This app would like to:
(1) Know who you are on Google
(2) View your email address
(3) View and manage the files and documents in your Google Drive

Some other text.

Cancel Button    Accept Button
```

The two buttons fall off the bottom of an iPhone 5 screen and need to be scrolled up to be seen and tapped.  I don't need to know "who you are on Google" or "your email address".  Is there a scope I can use that only manages Google Drive files so that the Accept button will appear on the initial view without needing to scroll up?  Or, is there some other way to auto-scroll to show the buttons?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is not a scope for what you are looking for. If you look at the [Drive 'About' request](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/about), you'll see why it results in the first 2 notes. There is not a scope that allows you to manage files and not see this information.

```
"kind": "drive#user",
"displayName": string,
"picture": {
  "url": string
},
"isAuthenticatedUser": boolean,
"permissionId": string,
"emailAddress": string
```

Answer (score 0):

Commenting out line 142 in GoogleAPI file "GTMOAuth2SignIn.m" results in the desired UI effect.  Unfortunately, the login fails and a long error message is displayed.  Perhaps someone with more knowledge of the GoogleAPI signin process can make it work.  Line 142 and the full procedure are as follows:

```
//scope = [GTMOAuth2Authentication scopeWithStrings:scope, emailScope, nil];


- (void)addScopeForGoogleUserInfo {
  GTMOAuth2Authentication *auth = self.authentication;
  if (self.shouldFetchGoogleUserEmail) {
    NSString *const emailScope = @"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email";
    NSString *scope = auth.scope;
    if ([scope rangeOfString:emailScope].location == NSNotFound) {
      //scope = [GTMOAuth2Authentication scopeWithStrings:scope, emailScope, nil];
      auth.scope = scope;
    }
  }

  if (self.shouldFetchGoogleUserProfile) {
    NSString *const profileScope = @"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile";
    NSString *scope = auth.scope;
    if ([scope rangeOfString:profileScope].location == NSNotFound) {
      scope = [GTMOAuth2Authentication scopeWithStrings:scope, profileScope, nil];
      auth.scope = scope;
    }
  }
}
```